# Spotfire control table values based on column value in another table

Tags: spotfire

I need to control the data being shown on table Collections and Delivery based on what I click on Table A column value on Spotfire.

For example we have the three tables below:

When the user clicks on a column on Dashboard Table let's say BO: BN. On Delivery and Collections Table only BO row should only appear.

How can you do this in Spotfire?

Note: The three tables have a relationship via Code and Branch column.
[image]

Additional data:
Collections and Deliveries table takes its data from DB using parameterized SQL Query.
There are three parameters that needs to be satisfied so that the query will work and data will be retrieved these are

StartDate
EndDate
Branch

I don't have a problem with the Date parameters but with the Branch see below SQL Query 

[image]

The branch parameter value is controlled by specifying/entering a value on the input field on text area. 

[image]

Deliveries and Collections table is configured to refer to this value to display the data.

[image]

[image]

The suggested solution worked great, but I have this extra dependency which makes it a bit more difficult to work out a solution. Do you have any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@dimas- One way to do this is creating detail visualization tables for Collections and Delivery from 'Dashboards table'.

Assuming that the three tables have relationship, please follow the below steps.

**Step 1:** Right click on Dashboards table and select `Create Details visualizations -> Table`. It prompts you to select a table, select 'Collections' tables.

**Step 2:** Repeat Step 1. But, this time select 'Delivery' table.

The Dashboards table now controls what data to show in Collections/Delivery tables based on the row selection.

**Output:**

[image]

Please ensure that you right click on the table and select `Properties > Data > All data` for Collections and Delivery table (screenshot below) if you want to show all rows if nothing is selected in Dashboards table.

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: your suggestion worked! thank you very much! However I do have another problem on the same set of data. The table for Deliveries and Collections are retrieved from DB using SQL query parameterized. So these two tables are dependent on the value of Branch which is a required parameter in the query. What i currently did to pull data from DB is to assign an input field and map the parameter with the assign variable for query in order to pull data. But this approach is having problem with the current approach. Do you have any ideas on how to go about this? Let me know if this is not clear.

Comment: @dimas - could you post this as a question with some screenshots? That would help in providing accurate solution. Thanks!

Comment: i have added screenshots and some information as you requested, appreciate if you can provide your feedback.

Comment: @dimas - As this question is different from the original one, I would suggest you to ask this as a separate question to get enough attention from SO users.